# How to show single points on a line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

My code is below. I am having an issue with plotting the pressure felt by a pressure sensor. If I change the format of the graph to:     `plt.plot(t, LBS_DATA_SENSOR1, 'c.')` it will work fine plotting the data with points. When I change it to 'c-' to make a line of line segments, however, it will not plot anything. The plot appears and the axis moves(both x and y) just like it is plotting in invisible ink. I know that the data is being received because it plots just fine with dots. I just can't get it to be lines!

```
#TE FX29 load cell sensor
#set up digital io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import RPi.GPIO as IO          #calling header file which helps us use GPIO’s of PI
IO.setwarnings(False)           #do not show any warnings
IO.setmode (IO.BCM)         #we are programming the GPIO by BCM pin numbers. (PIN35 as    ‘GPIO19’)
IO.setup(19,IO.OUT)           # initialize GPIO19 as an output, not important for the pressure     sensor or load cell
#set up i2c
import time
import smbus
from time import sleep
bus = smbus.SMBus(1) #I2C channel 1 is connected to the GPIO pins 2 (SDA) and 4 (SCL)
channel = 1          #select channel
t=0
plt.figure()
#Condition sensor for continuous measurements
LOAD_SENSOR_ADDRESS=0x28
dummy_command=0x00
offset=1000
#offset=int((input("Enter offset value, default 1000:") or 1000))                                            #subtracts zero offset per data sheet, should be 1000
LOAD_SENSOR_DATA=bus.read_byte(LOAD_SENSOR_ADDRESS)#This apparently turns the load sensor on,    only need it once
running_max = 0
#take continuous measurements and report
while 1:
    bus.write_byte(LOAD_SENSOR_ADDRESS,dummy_command)                                              #without this command, the status bytes go high on every other read
    LOAD_SENSOR_DATA=bus.read_i2c_block_data(LOAD_SENSOR_ADDRESS,dummy_command,2)      
    LBS_DATA_SENSOR1=((LOAD_SENSOR_DATA[0]&63)*2**8 + LOAD_SENSOR_DATA[1] - offset)*100/14000                                                                                  #It does return the correct two bytes after the initial read byte command    
    if LBS_DATA_SENSOR1 > running_max:
        running_max = LBS_DATA_SENSOR1
    plt.plot(t, LBS_DATA_SENSOR1, 'c-')
    plt.xlim(0, t+1)
    plt.ylim(0, running_max + 10)
    plt.pause(0.01)
    t += .01
```

I have looked in the documentation and tried to change the line style to many things but it always ends up plotting nothing or plotting modified dots in whatever size and color I wanted the line to be. I have asked Chat GPT, I have added a wait time for the program to catch up and I have searched the internet for solutions but I have come up empty handed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to plot a single point using a line, so nothing will be drawn. You need two x points and two y points to define a line. What you can do is save the data into a list and keep updating the plot. This can be done in two ways. The first method is manual, where you create lists to store the data and update them in each loop. The second method accesses the data stored in the line object and appends more data each loop. I think the first method is more readable (and the animation seemed less glitchy, for some reason).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = x**3

# option 1
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([],[], "c-")

# you will store the data in lists and append new data to those lists
xdata = []
ydata = []
for _x, _y in zip(x, y):
    xdata.append(_x)
    ydata.append(_y)
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.pause(0.01)
    
# option 2
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([],[], "c-")
for _x, _y in zip(x, y):
    line.set_xdata(np.append(line.get_xdata(), _x))
    line.set_ydata(np.append(line.get_ydata(), _y))
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.pause(0.01)
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes so much sense! I appreciate the quick response!

Comment: I used method 1 and it worked great!